# Getting C++ working on Win10

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

So last semester in school we learned Java in Eclipse.

I need to learn C++ and I am so horribly confused on how to actually get this set up.

Im trying to do **Eclipse CDT + GCC**

I've googled around and watched a few guides, but everything is slightly outdated, theres like 93485 different java jdk and jre links with info.

I've installed both, and gotten eclipse to launch with a new install of jre in its folder, I also installed GCC to C:/MinGW and did something where i added its path to system.

Then under eclipse I've managed to get a working structure with file--> new --> C/C++ prj--> A managed build and selecting miniGW off to the side.
When i try to run the program I get launch failed, binary not found and tried following the steps here
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/824895/

when I tried the debugg method, i now get the error: error starting process..

I started following a new guide on a new install, In the video it references checking if java is installed by typing "javac" into cmd. Which didnt work for me, so I (re)installed JDK now, dunno the difference between JDK and JRE, and now i still get the same error in CMD.

SO CONFUSED, what is going on here, can anyone help me out please?

Comment: You can try visual studio if you are working on windows. It is an excellent IDE in my opinion.

Comment: 1st choice Visual Studio Community Edition: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ ; 2nd choice Code::Blocks (bundled g++); 3rd choice Eclipse+CDT

Comment: ***I need to learn C++ and I am so horribly confused on how to actually get this set up.*** I third the advice to install Visual Studio 2017 Community instead. If you want gcc/mingw. I recommend QtCreator or code::blocks.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't ship with a compiler. Since you're using Windows and Eclipse, [I recommend a vanilla MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php). Install it into it's default folder and then make sure the folder was added to the system path. There's better out there, but beating it into working with Eclipse gets harder. If you just want to start writing code, I'm with the other four. Pass and use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to start with C++ on Windows. I will refer to the method I'm using -

1. First install MinGW compiler. Make sure it gets added to your PATH.
2. Then install [CLion IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/). Since, you are a student you might get a year of subscription. I got it when I installed and signed up on their website.
3. Start the IDE - it will ask you to create a new project.

You are done. The main advantages of having an IDE (instead of a simple editor) is that it makes your coding more organised and easy to maintain. Other than that you get debugging feature and intellisense like features which come handy during use.

However, if you want a simple lightweight tool, somewhere between an editor and an IDE then I recommend you to use [Dev-C++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/latest/download) (the link version also includes a compiler). Here, you don't have to worry about creating new projects (though you can create a project if you want, but it is not necessary) - just install and create new file each time you want to write a program and run it.  However, you won't get debugging feature.

Comment: Ive tried to install this MINGW thing 100 different ways,
I went to system, environment and added this
https://i.imgur.com/aO7aziC.png

I cant get this to work in eclipse still, also looking into CLion, emailed them about free student license.

Comment: As I said, you can try Dev-C++. The version in the link comes with inbuilt compiler. So, you don't have to worry about installing additional compiler and adding it to PATH. But for CLion you need to install a compiler (like MinGW).